# default argument function signature change

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a function whose current signature is f(a,b=0). I want to add another argument c. I want my function in such a way so that I can call f(a,b) which is currently the behavior and f(a,c). One way is to overload the function and duplicate the function code. I do not want to call f(a,b) from f(a,c). I am working in C++.

Is there any standard design pattern or a solution which can avoid this code duplication ?

Comment: that doesn't make alot of sense to me...

Comment: neither does it for me... why don't you have 3 arguments in your function?

Comment: You want to have two functions of the same name that take the same types but perform differently?!

Comment: You've asked this question in a very confusing way - it's difficult to understand what you're trying to do.  Maybe a snippet of example code will help (and give the types for the function parameters, since that's what matters in overloading).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not completely sure I follow you, but you can use variations on this:

```
void f(int a, int b=0, int c=0);
void f2(int a, int c=0) { f(a, 0, c); }
```

Notice that no code is duplicated. And now you have another function that calls your first function but allows you to specify the third argument rather than the second.